# SQL select transactions derived from other transactions and group them with original transactions

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table where you can see the list of transactions where some transactions are derived from another transactions. What I would like to get is to select the list of transactions and group them with its derivatives (those where the value in ORIGIN_TXN_ID is equal to the value in TXN_ID). Do you have any idea how to get such these results?

Many thanks for your help.

Table **Transactions**:

```
TXN_ID   ORIGIN_TXN_ID    TXN_STATUS
------------------------------------
ID001                     F
ID002                     F
ID003                     F
ID004                     F
ID104    ID001            F
ID105    ID001            F
ID106    ID002            F
```

Expected results:

```
TXN_ID   ORIGIN_TXN_ID
------------------------
ID001
ID104    ID001
ID105    ID001
ID002
ID106    ID002
```

Comment: In expected results the ID003 and ID004 have been omitted? Or were the results truncated?  If omitted, then the first task would be to insure that at least one derivative was present.  What sql with GroupBy  would you write for that?  Here we are trying to solve one part at a time.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that another way to see this problem is that you want to omit the duplicate `txn_id` - `origin_txn_id` null pair if a `txn_id` - `origin_txn_id` non null pair exists.

```
With cte 
As
(
Select distinct  txn_id, origin_txn_id from table 
Where origin_txn_id is not null )
Select * from cte

Union

Select distinct txn_id, origin_txn_id from table where 
Txn_id not in ( select txn_id from cte)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find out the rows where Txn_Id is either present in the ORIGIN_TXN_ID column or Txn_Id has a NOT NULL value in ORIGIN_TXN_ID column.

```
SELECT TXN_ID, ORIGIN_TXN_ID 
FROM Transactions
WHERE ( ORIGIN_TXN_ID IS NOT NULL OR
TXN_ID IN (SELECT ORIGIN_TXN_ID FROM Transactions))
GROUP BY TXN_ID, ORIGIN_TXN_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a simple `union all`:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.orign_txn_id is not null
union all
select t.*
from transactions t
where t.txn_id in (select t2.orign_txn_id
                   from transactions t2
                  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right, by "group" you rather mean sort. I also assume, that there are only two levels in the hierarchy -- parent and child paths but no grandparent, parent and child path.

To sort the way you want `ORDER BY` the concatenation of `origin_txn_id` and `txn_id`. The `origin_txn_id` has to be replaced with an empty string if it's `NULL`. This works because, from two strings where one string is the beginning of the other, the shorter one gets sorted first.

```
SELECT t1.*
       FROM transactions t1
       ORDER BY concat(coalesce(t1.origin_txn_id, ''), t1.txn_id);
```

- `concat()` is used to concatenate the strings. `concat()` is available in most DBMS. If yours doesn't support it, it will have other means of string concatenation, e.g. the `||` operator.
- `coalesce()` returns the first non-null value of the expressions given to it. So it returns the empty string if `origin_txn_id` is null. Again `coalesce()` is available in most DBMS, if not there will be something similar. Or the `concat()` in your DBMS automatically concatenates empty strings instead of `NULL`s. Then `coalesce()` isn't needed at all.

I'm not sure, if you also want to exclude transactions, that have no children. If you want to do that, add a `WHERE` clause checking, that a row is a child or has children using `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT t1.*
       FROM transactions t1
       WHERE t1.origin_txn_id IS NOT NULL
              OR EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM transactions t2
                                WHERE t2.origin_txn_id = t1.txn_id)
       ORDER BY concat(coalesce(t1.origin_txn_id, ''), t1.txn_id);
```